# Combining 3 different MySQL databases to show user info?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently building a private messaging system on my website. The problem I am having, in your "inbox" the messages you have sent or received are displayed with the title of (SUBJECT). When you click the subject, you can see all the messages you or the other user have sent to each other with first and last names.

The 2 codes below gather this information from the databases, which is absolutely fine. Although, instead of showing the (SUBJECT) on the "inbox" page, I would prefer to show the (FIRST NAME + LAST NAME) of who the message is to or from, just like you can see in the actual message itself. I cannot figure out how to do this.

The second code below does this for the view message page, although the top code gathers information for the inbox page, I have tried my best to combine the users info from the 2nd part to the 1st part, but all this does is show every message as the logged in users first and last names, not who the message is sent to or received from, is there a way to do this? Here are the 2 codes:

```
<?php
function fetch_conversation_summery(){
    $sql = "SELECT
                `conversations`.`conversation_id`,
                `conversations`.`conversation_subject`,
                MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) AS `conversation_last_reply`,
                MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `conversation_unread`
            FROM `conversations`
            LEFT JOIN `conversations_messages` ON `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id`
            INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
            WHERE `conversations_members`.`userid` = {$_SESSION['userid']}
            AND `conversations_members`.`conversation_deleted` = 0
            GROUP BY `conversations`.`conversation_id`
            ORDER BY `conversation_last_reply` DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $conversations = array();

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
        $conversations[] = array(
            'id'               => $row['conversation_id'],
            'subject'          => $row['conversation_subject'],
            'last_reply'       => $row['conversation_last_reply'],    
            'name'       => $row['first_name'],            
            'unread_messages'  => ($row['conversation_unread'] == 1),

        );
    }

    return $conversations;
}

function fetch_conversation_messages($conversation_id){
    $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

    $sql = "SELECT
                  `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
                  `conversations_messages`.`message_date` > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `message_unread`,
                  `conversations_messages`.`message_text`,
                  `users`.`first_name`,
                  `users`.`last_name`
            FROM `conversations_messages`
            INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`userid` = `users`.`userid`
            INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
            WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
            AND `conversations_members`.`userid` = {$_SESSION['userid']}
            ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $messages = array();

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
        $messages[] = array(
                'date'     => $row['message_date'],
                'unread'   => $row['message_unread'],
                'text'     => $row['message_text'],
                'first_name' => $row['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $row['last_name'],
        );
    }

    return $messages;
}
```

I need to be able to recall the information as `"$conversation['first_name'];` `$conversation['last_name']"` to show the names, although this information is only available on the messages page as `"$messages['first_name'];`. I am currently displaying the subject as `"$conversation['subject'];`". Trying to turn subject into the first and last names. Thanks